# C# can't declare public double array of Int: Field is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors

I am getting an error on this line:

`public int[][] mySpiros;`

The error is as is:

`Field Spirograph.myList.mySpiros is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null`.

Now this line is written in a class. I only wanted to create a double array so I can store my future parameters for each drawings (spirographs) generated by the user.

Edit: Seems like instantiating multiple arrays of `integers` is not Microsoft's favorite action:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to instantiate the array?

Comment: I have tried `public int[][] mySpiros = new int[50][];` (putting an index to the second brackets is throwing an error) put it still shows the warning and pops up an error everytime I start the application.

Comment: You have to instantiate this way: `public int[][] mySpiros = new int[3] { int[5], int[5], int[5] };`

Comment: Since my array is not of fixed length, I must be prepared to have more than 1000 array of arrays... do I need to instantiate all of them?

Comment: Yes you have to. But if you have 1000 arrays, I guess it will be done somewhere in a loop in your code. The main thing is that at some point in your code it must be done. Otherwise you won't get rid of this warning and your array and/or (some of) its subarrays will be equal to `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating [array of arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) so you need to instantiate arrays like:

```
public int[][] mySpiros;

//create three reference variables to hold array references
mySpiros=new int[3][];

mySpiros[0]=new int[4];
mySpiros[1]=new int[] {11,22,33,44};
mySpiros[2]=new int[40];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a warning, and not an error. Make sure you haven't set "Treat Warning as Error" in the Project setting. Right click on project->Properties and set this: [Screenshot](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_MtIkzYP1hdI/TdoCKJWdBJI/AAAAAAAAAJA/qMusgujgX6Q/treat%20warnings%20as%20errors%5B6%5D.png)

Make sure it is set to "None". That should allow you to build and run.

Be aware, this warning means your code is never creating an instance of this field, which in turn will generate null reference exception!